# Webservice API that use another Webservice API

Tags: web-services, api

I want to provide a geolocation API servce so end users can send IP and the API return geo information about the IP.
While the ideal would be to install a database on my server the database providers like Maxmind, ip2location etc suggest to directly query their API service.

This doesn't sound right to me as the end user will have a query to my API + the query from my API to the provider.

Is this doable ? or I should take a different approach ?

Comment: I am curious why you'd build your own service if others exist that do the same thing. Is there a value-add you have planned for your service? Also consider this - if you build one and you depend on another, your client now has two points of failure that could break their call to you - you're down or the service you call is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is doable, just that it boils down to whether this is a practical/sound approach based on what you want to achieve. Below are a few drawbacks by doing this based on my opinion.

- The overhead cost is too expensive, as it involves the calling to your own API server + the query to an external 3rd party API solution.
- The query speed will be slow due to too high the latency.
- You solution will be depending on the 3rd party server uptime, which you have no much control of this.
- Any point of failure on either your server or 3rd party server will bring down your API.

Unless you have a good reason for this, the best solution would be to host your own geolocation database and build the API service on top. You can either use [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com) or [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com) database, whichever you like.